# keeping an object persistent across function calls

Tags: matlab, user-interface, scope

I asked a question earlier in regards to keeping a variable persistent across function calls and I was wondering if you could do something similar with objects.

for example if i had a piece of code like this:

```
 function Gui(backofplayingcard,store,card)
 v = 1; 
 w = 1200;
 h = 550;
 f = figure('visible', 'off','color','white','position',[1 1 w h]);

 movegui(f,'center');

 set(f,'visible','on','name','matching game');



  % create 6 by 6 grid with a picture above a pushbutton for each location
  % on the grid

  for p = 1:6
  for w = 1:6

  subplot(6,6,((p - 1) * 6 + w) );
  imshow(backofplayingcard);

  button(v) =    uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','value',"some value dependent on p and w",'String','Flip!','Position',...
[[(152 * (w)) + ((w) * 10) + 25] [((7 - p) * 69) - ((p) * 10) + 33]  60 20],...
'Callback',{@flip});
 v = v + 1;

 end
 end
 end
```

would there be a way for me to store the first object I called with a handle. So
for example:

```
      function flip(hObject,eventdata)
      persistent a;
      if isempty(a)
      handle1 = hObject;
      a = 1;
      else
      check1 = get(handle1,'value');
      check2 = get(hObject,'value');

     if check1 == check2

       disp('hello');

     else 
        disp('goodbye');

     end
     end
     end
```

Such that MATLAB would remember the first object i called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in my (not very well received) answer to your previous question, I would recommend using the handles structure to store data shared among callbacks.

For this case, I would add a custom tag to every pushbutton created in your loop, which would make it easy to know which buttons have been pressed and in what order. For example, let's say the tag is created like so in the loop:

```
sprintf('Button %i',(p - 1) * 6 + w))
```

Basically every button will be tagged with its number. You can change this to a simple number if you want.

In order to get a list of all the buttons pressed, you can simply concatenate them vertically in the `flip` function, so you will have a cell array (in my example, but that could be a numeric array depending on the tag you choose) containing the `Tag` of each of the button that were pressed. I also added a counter to the handles structure in case you wanted to know how many buttons were pushed...

I don't mean to bug you with this, but storing variables in the handles structure of a GUI is a safe way to make sure they are all easily accessible from every callback.

So here is your code with a few additions. You can tune it as you like. I added

```
%// ===== NEW =====
```

to point new stuff I added.

You can copy/paste this code as a new .m file and see what `handles.ListFlip` looks like every time you press the pushbutton.

```
function CardGui

clc
clear

v = 1;
w = 1200;
h = 550;

%// Demo image 
backofplayingcard = imread('coins.png');

f = figure('visible', 'off','color','white','position',[1 1 w h]);

movegui(f,'center');

set(f,'visible','on','name','matching game');

%// ==== NEW ====
%// Initialize cell array containing list of buttons and counter.
handles.ListFlip = cell(1,1);
handles.flipCounter = 0;
%// =============

% create 6 by 6 grid with a picture above a pushbutton for each location
% on the grid

for p = 1:6
    for w = 1:6

        subplot(6,6,((p - 1) * 6 + w) );
        imshow(backofplayingcard);

        %// ==== NEW ====
        %// Added the buttons to the handles structure and gave them tags
        handles.button(v) =    uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','value',0,'String','Flip!','Position',...
            [(152 * (w)) + ((w) * 10) + 25 ((7 - p) * 69) - ((p) * 10) + 33  60 20],...
            'Callback',{@flip},'Tag',sprintf('Button %i',(p - 1) * 6 + w));
        v = v + 1;

    end
end

guidata(f,handles);

    function flip(hObject,~)

        handles = guidata(f);

        %// ==== NEW ====
        %// Get current button selected (using its tag)
        CurrentButton = get(hObject,'Tag');

        %// Add it to the list

        if handles.flipCounter  == 0
         handles.ListFlip = CurrentButton;   
        else
         handles.ListFlip = [handles.ListFlip;CurrentButton];
        end

        handles.flipCounter  = handles.flipCounter +1;
        %// =============

        guidata(f,handles)
    end
end
```

Sample output in the Command Window after I pressed 3 buttons:

```
Button 1
Button 3
Button 6
```

Hope that helps. You can combine this code with the answer you received to your previous question and all should work well.

Comment: It took me some time playing around with the debugger and echo function to figure out how storing objects in structures works, but everything worked perfectly once i got it, Thanks.